# c# Web API escaping characters and combining fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am working in Web API 2.2 and Entity Framework 6.1. I am retrieving an address field from the database that looks like this:

```
"740 Washington Heights Rd \T\".
```

When that field is returned as Json any fields following it are combined with the Address field like this:

```
"Address1": "740 Wahsington Heights Rd \\T\\","Address2":null,"City":"ElCajon"
```

But it should look like this:

```
"Address1": "740 Wahsington Heights Rd \T\",
"Address2":null,
"City":"ElCajon"
```

What can I do to fix this? It is a standard EntityFramework Model and Controller in the Web API Service.

Comment: Wrong.  `\`s must be escaped for valid JSON.  You don't actually have a problem.

Comment: And if you're talking about the newlines, those don't matter either.

Comment: After several tests, I have discovered that it is only when the \ is the last character in the string when this occurs. (There should only be 2 "\\" in the second set, not 3. (-Fixed in edit)

Comment: The quotes are not in the database.  I added them for clarity but I guess caused confusion.

Comment: What's the problem? The JSON representation of the string 740 Wahsington Heights Rd \T\ is `"740 Wahsington Heights Rd \\T\\"`. Everything looks okay...

Comment: the problem is that the json for Address1 goes to the end of ElCajon and is not separated like it should be in a normal json return of this object.  This causes a problem when I fill my entity.  this entity when filled has a property called Address1 with a value of: "740 Wahsington Heights Rd \\T\\","Address2":null,"City":"ElCajon" and an empty Address2 property and an empty City property.

Comment: I should add that this is completely automatic and I am not doing anything special. The entity is being filled by Entity Framework.